# How to refer to a single frame in a an object class?

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I have my character movieclip on frame1 of my timeline. When it hits an enemy the movie goes on frame2 where I have a game-over screen. However I get this error at runtime when the character hits the enemy:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at Coinsy/update()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_2_fla::MainTimeline/CharMovement()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_2_fla::MainTimeline/ResetBox()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_2_fla::MainTimeline/EnemyBall()
```

I debugged and it seems that the problem is in my coins class:

```
package  

    {
        import flash.display.*;
        import flash.events.*;

        public class Coinsy extends MovieClip

        {
            var char:MovieClip;
            var MTL = MovieClip(root);

            public function Coinsy() 
            {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            }
            function update(event:Event):void
            {
                char = MTL.char1;
                // CC = int(root).CC;

                if(hitTestObject(char))
                {
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                    MTL.CC++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

at `char = MTL.char1;`, apparently I can't use `MovieClip(root)` when I have more then one frame.

char1 is my character's instance name andCC is the coin count var.

I'm pretty new at ActionScript and I'd like to know where i did wrong. THANKS!

Comment: `Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.` means that char is null when it gets passed to the function. You can fix it by writing `if(char != null && hitTestObject(char))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually happening on this line

```
if(hitTestObject(char))
```

What's happening is the game is still trying to check for collisions on the game-over screen. The `char1` object couldn't be found, so it became null. Null essentially means something's empty, so you can't do anything with it. If you ever try `null.something` you'll get an error, and `someFunction(null)` will quite likely cause an error too.

A quick fix is changing the line to

```
if(char != null && hitTestObject(char))
```

as Karma mentioned.

However, the following three TypeErrors are unrelated to the code you posted. They're happening because some line of code is trying to do `null.something`. The `CharMovement`, `ResetBox` and `EnemyBall` functions are probably being called when they shouldn't be. You might need to remove event listeners when game-over happens, or add extra logic to check for null values.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also removed the event listeners and I have no error output.